# Subsetting a gps-track dataset based on time intervals gathered from a second dataset

Tags: r, date, time, match, subset

I have a large gps-track dataset and I want to extract only the positions taken while an observer was on duty.  In other terms, I need to cut the gps-tracks in several transects in which an observer was watching. The watching periods are in a second DB in which the observer registered the start and end of (roughly hourly) watching periods, so that the start time and end time registered for each day marks the start and end of the watch period for that day in most cases. However, it can happen that the watching was paused for some reason and then restarted some time later on the same day, so that two consecutive annotations can have a time gap between them.

I was trying with match() and dplyr:filter() functions but can't came out with a solution. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Below it is a simplified example

DB1  (very large gps track to subset)

```
   date         time   lat      lon     
1  18/04/2017   6:10   34.01    -53.07
2  18/04/2017   6:20   34.02    -53.09
3  18/04/2017   6:30   34.04    -53.10
4  18/04/2017   6:40   34.05    -53.11
5  18/04/2017   6:50   34.07    -53.13
6  18/04/2017   7:00   34.08    -53.14
7  18/04/2017   7:10   34.01    -53.07
8  18/04/2017   7:20   34.02    -53.09
9  18/04/2017   7:30   34.04    -53.10
.      .         .       .         .
.      .         .       .         .
.      .         .       .         .
n   19/04/2017  6:10   34.05    -53.11
n+1 19/04/2017  6:20   34.07    -53.13
n+2 19/04/2017  6:30   34.08    -53.14
```

DB2 (watching periods)

```
    date          start.watch   end.watch
1   2017-04-18    05:00         06:10
2   2017-04-18    06:10         06:30
3   2017-04-18    06:30         06:45
4   2017-04-18    07:20         08:20
.      .            .             . 
.      .            .             . 
.      .            .             . 
n   2017-04-19    06:20         07:20
n+1 2017-04-19    07:20         08:40
```

Resulting DB should be:`

```
1  18/04/2017   6:10   34.01    -53.07
2  18/04/2017   6:20   34.02    -53.09
3  18/04/2017   6:30   34.04    -53.10
4  18/04/2017   6:40   34.05    -53.11

8  18/04/2017   7:20   34.02    -53.09
9  18/04/2017   7:30   34.04    -53.10

n   19/04/2017  6:10   34.05    -53.11
n+1 19/04/2017  6:20   34.07    -53.13
n+2 19/04/2017  6:30   34.08    -53.14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative that does a range-based (fuzzy) join based on time overlaps. It uses `data.table::foverlaps`, which does require (at least for this join) that the two frames be proper `data.table` objects, because it needs the keys to be clearly set.

This method has a few requirements:

1. All timestamps are easily comparable numerically, I'll convert them to `POSIXt` objects;
2. Keys are set for at least the second table (and might help in the first). The last two keys for each must be the beginning and end of each time interval; and
3. Yes, you read that right, even the "single time observations" need two timestamp fields.

NB: I use `magrittr` solely to break out the process into a pipeline of sorts; it is not at all required, just makes it easier to read. Also, I use `copy()` and `setDT` and then assign to a new variable primarily because (1) I iterated a few times but wanted to start with fresh data each time; and more importantly (2) because `data.table` operates in *side-effect*, I want to encourage you to try this but not kill your local data until you are comfortable working with it in side-effect. You can easily un-`data.table`-ize it after the fact.

First, I'll set up the needed conditions.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

DB1dt <- copy(DB1) %>%
  setDT() %>%
  .[, dt := as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") ] %>%
  # remove unneeded columns
  .[, c("date", "time") := NULL ] %>%
  .[, dt2 := dt ] %>%
  setkey(dt, dt2)

DB2dt <- copy(DB2) %>%
  setDT() %>%
  .[, startdt := as.POSIXct(paste(date, start.watch), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") ] %>%
  .[, enddt := as.POSIXct(paste(date, end.watch), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") - 1e-5 ] %>%
  # remove unneeded columns
  .[, c("date", "start.watch", "end.watch") := NULL ] %>%
  setkey(startdt, enddt)

DB1dt[1:2,]
#      lat    lon                  dt                 dt2
# 1: 34.01 -53.07 2017-04-18 06:10:00 2017-04-18 06:10:00
# 2: 34.02 -53.09 2017-04-18 06:20:00 2017-04-18 06:20:00
DB2dt[1:2,]
#                startdt               enddt
# 1: 2017-04-18 05:00:00 2017-04-18 06:09:59
# 2: 2017-04-18 06:10:00 2017-04-18 06:29:59
```

FYI: the use of `-1e-5` is because the "within"-join is closed on both ends (`[a,b]`, in constrast to open-right `[a,b)`), so equality on `enddt` would match. Over to you if you want to keep this.

From here, the overlapping join is simply:

```r
foverlaps(DB1dt, DB2dt, type = "within", nomatch = NULL)
#                startdt               enddt   lat    lon                  dt                 dt2
# 1: 2017-04-18 06:10:00 2017-04-18 06:29:59 34.01 -53.07 2017-04-18 06:10:00 2017-04-18 06:10:00
# 2: 2017-04-18 06:10:00 2017-04-18 06:29:59 34.02 -53.09 2017-04-18 06:20:00 2017-04-18 06:20:00
# 3: 2017-04-18 06:30:00 2017-04-18 06:44:59 34.04 -53.10 2017-04-18 06:30:00 2017-04-18 06:30:00
# 4: 2017-04-18 06:30:00 2017-04-18 06:44:59 34.05 -53.11 2017-04-18 06:40:00 2017-04-18 06:40:00
# 5: 2017-04-18 07:20:00 2017-04-18 08:19:59 34.02 -53.09 2017-04-18 07:20:00 2017-04-18 07:20:00
# 6: 2017-04-18 07:20:00 2017-04-18 08:19:59 34.04 -53.10 2017-04-18 07:30:00 2017-04-18 07:30:00
# 7: 2017-04-19 06:20:00 2017-04-19 07:19:59 34.07 -53.13 2017-04-19 06:20:00 2017-04-19 06:20:00
# 8: 2017-04-19 06:20:00 2017-04-19 07:19:59 34.08 -53.14 2017-04-19 06:30:00 2017-04-19 06:30:00
```

---

Sample data:

```r
DB1 <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = "
date         time   lat      lon     
18/04/2017   6:10   34.01    -53.07
18/04/2017   6:20   34.02    -53.09
18/04/2017   6:30   34.04    -53.10
18/04/2017   6:40   34.05    -53.11
18/04/2017   6:50   34.07    -53.13
18/04/2017   7:00   34.08    -53.14
18/04/2017   7:10   34.01    -53.07
18/04/2017   7:20   34.02    -53.09
18/04/2017   7:30   34.04    -53.10
19/04/2017   6:10   34.05    -53.11
19/04/2017   6:20   34.07    -53.13
19/04/2017   6:30   34.08    -53.14")

DB2 <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = "
date          start.watch   end.watch
2017-04-18    05:00         06:10
2017-04-18    06:10         06:30
2017-04-18    06:30         06:45
2017-04-18    07:20         08:20
2017-04-19    06:20         07:20
2017-04-19    07:20         08:40")
```

---

Related reading:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/224705
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3721

Comment: @giocomai, sorry for the delay in giving feedback. I posted my question and then leaved for some days.  
 Apart of having been surprisingly quick, your responses worked fine for me, so many thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is, I think, the solution to your question.

The code should be clear, but in brief, the key part is to create datetime columns and intervals with the `lubridate` package, and then use `lubridate`'s `%within%` function to check if a given time is inside the given intervals.

Hope this helps.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

db1 <- tribble(~date, ~time, ~lat, ~lon,
               "18/04/2017", "6:10", 34.01, -53.07,
               "18/04/2017", "6:20", 34.02, -53.09,
               "18/04/2017", "6:30", 34.04, -53.10,
               "18/04/2017", "6:40", 34.05, -53.11,
               "18/04/2017", "6:50", 34.07, -53.13,
               "18/04/2017", "7:00", 34.08, -53.14,
               "18/04/2017", "7:10", 34.01, -53.07,
               "18/04/2017", "7:20", 34.02, -53.09,
               "18/04/2017", "7:30", 34.04, -53.10
)

db2 <- tribble(~date, ~start.watch, ~end.watch,
               "2017-04-18", "05:00", "06:10",
               "2017-04-18", "06:10", "06:30",
               "2017-04-18", "06:30", "06:45",
               "2017-04-18", "07:20", "08:20")


db2_intervals <- db2 %>% 
  mutate(end_date = date) %>% 
  unite("start_datetime", date, start.watch) %>% 
  unite("end_datetime", end_date, end.watch) %>% 
  transmute(interval = interval(start = ymd_hm(start_datetime),
                                end = ymd_hm(end_datetime))) %>% 
  pull(interval)


db1 %>% 
  unite("datetime", date, time) %>% 
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime)) %>% 
  filter(datetime %within% as.list(db2_intervals)) 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   datetime              lat   lon
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2017-04-18 06:10:00  34.0 -53.1
#> 2 2017-04-18 06:20:00  34.0 -53.1
#> 3 2017-04-18 06:30:00  34.0 -53.1
#> 4 2017-04-18 06:40:00  34.0 -53.1
#> 5 2017-04-18 07:20:00  34.0 -53.1
#> 6 2017-04-18 07:30:00  34.0 -53.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @r2Evans and giocomai, sorry for the delay in giving feedback. I posted my question and then leaved for some days.  
 Apart of having been surprisingly quick, your responses worked fine for me, so many thanks to both of you!